# Echo the environment variable of HADOOP_HDFS_HOME doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, environment-variables

*Ubuntu 16.04 and hadoop yarn*

I installed hadoop in `/usr/local/hadoop` and needed to edit a few environment variables which are located in `/etc/environment`.

I tried to edit them via wah in root mode.

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
HADOOP_HDFS_HOME="/usr/local/hadoop"
```

My console Inputs after the edits:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME => Is it OK for root mode or not?

echo $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME => It displays nothing unless I use that command in root mode.
```

I tried to edit the environment variables in other ways, but it is still the same.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to write in understandable English. It doesn't need to be perfect, but we should understand what you want to know. :)

Comment: Thanks you note and sorry for my bad english. I'll try my best to improve it

Answer (score 0):

> after the edits

Did you try to either open a brand new terminal or `source /etc/environment` before echoing? Your edits will not be reflected until you do this

And if you want to edit a variable for a particular user, not the entire system, put the variables in a `~/.profile` file